# Laravel (5.6) - где находится Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: laravel5

Вместе с фреймворком Laravel по умолчанию поставляется Bootstrap 4.0 (кажется, beta). В дефолтном файле стилей `app.scss` находится следующая строчка

`@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Куда указывает "`~`"? Где найти этот исходник bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Laravel исходный код фреймворка Bootstrap находится в папке `node_modules`. (Если её нет, нужно выполнить команду `npm install`).

Поэтому, "`~`" в пути указывает на папку `node_modules`.